# Does Fallout: New Vegas support character slots?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I know it's a pretty broad question, but does anybody know if you can have "character slots" for Fallout: New Vegas? What I'm looking for is a system similar to how Dark Souls has different slots where you can make different "themed" characters. I am aware of different save editors, but I'm looking for something where I can choose different characters in game more easily.

Comment: Sorry, we don't do mod recommendations, I'm afraid.

Comment: I know but I'm kind of at a loss since I've spent the last 6 hours searching nexus for something along these lines.

Comment: @Frank He asks about the existence of such a mod, therefore I would allow it since he is not asking "do you recommend mod a or b". It could use some rewording though to make it more conform.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Problem is, the question you propose will get the same sort of answers as the original question.  That said, this edit takes it away from recommendations, so I have no issues with it.

Comment: Note that regardless of the wording, mod recommendation questions per se are *not* off-topic here. (As per http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/is-mod-rec-really-an-umbrella-category-that-we-want-to-use-or-is-it-confusing and http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/closed-mod-recommendation-skyrim-question-can-this-question-be-improved-and )

Comment: @galacticninja And as I keep saying, yes, they *are*.  As evidenced by [our latest meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8147/the-community-is-closing-mod-rec-questions) about them, and mod actions I've observed of them doing that exact thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not how the save system works and you cannot change with mods how the game saves.

What you can do though is to open the console with `^` (QWERZT) or `~` (QWERTY), depending on your layout and give the savegame a name, e.g:

```
save "SniperLOL"
save "MeleePwnage"
```

That is as far as it can get with character management in FO:NV. For more information on Keyboard Commands, see [this thread on Steam](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1769318). You only need to do this once, e.g. after creating your character, if you overwrite it, it will retain the name. The name you give the save is also reflected on your harddisc.

*ps.: If you care about achievements, you need to restart your game after saving with this method, otherwise you are not going to get any and they won't be rewarded retroactively.*

Comment: It's a shame they don't already have this/support the option to have it.

Comment: I think I managed to stumble on what I've been looking for [here](http://www.nexusmods.com/newvegas/mods/36730/?) . Can't be certain as I'm currently downloading a fresh copy of the game but we'll see.

Comment: The mod I linked above sort of meets expectations,  I'm currently modding it to meet all of them :p Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @slow_excellence Well it injects code into FO:NV to allow more than normally possible, so my statement is still correct considering the default abilities of the editor.